# Vue3 jgile / vue-csv-import Save Mapping / Inject Mapping

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I have the csv import component installed and running ( https://github.com/jgile/vue-csv-import ).

Now I want to save the mapping and if a saved mapping is aviable, it should map from the previously mapped and saved object.

The mapping is in VueCsvImportData.map but I´m unable to pass down mapping props to the VueCsvMap.vue component.

Has anyone already made this or has anyone some tips how to pass the needed data to get this to work?

Thank you!

I have a custom Upload.vue, where I want to manipulate for example the VueCsvImportData.VueCsvImportData.map field ks_tgz.

```
    <template>
    <div v-if="checkUser" class="h-screen flex flex-col p-6 w-full">
        <div class="mb-4">
            <span class="text-xl font-heading">CSV Upload</span>
        </div>
        <vue-csv-import
            v-model="csv"
            ref="VueCsvImportData"
            :fields="felder"
            v-bind:text="{
                toggleHeaders: 'Erste Zeile ist Überschrift',
                fieldColumn: 'Feld',
                csvColumn: 'CSV Spaltenbezeichnung'
                }" 
            >
            <div>
                <vue-csv-errors></vue-csv-errors>
            </div>
            <div class="mt-4">
                <vue-csv-input></vue-csv-input>
            </div>
            <div class="mt-4">
                <vue-csv-toggle-headers 
                    v-bind:labelAttributes="{class: 'text-blue-500 font-heading'}"
                    v-bind:checkboxAttributes="{class: 'checked:bg-blue-600'}"
                    >
                </vue-csv-toggle-headers>
            </div>
            <div class="mt-4 w-full">
                <vue-csv-map
                    v-bind:selectAttributes="{class: 'rounded border-2 border-gray-300 w-11/12'}"
                >
                </vue-csv-map>
            </div>
        </vue-csv-import>
        
        <div class="mt-4">
            <knopf @click.prevent="senden" v-bind:knopfValues="{ name: 'Senden!!', bg: 'bg-yellow-500', txt: 'text-white'}"/>
        </div>
       
        <div v-if="VueCsvImportData" class="mt-4">
            {{ VueCsvImportData.VueCsvImportData.map }}
            <span v-on:click="changeMap">Change</span>
        </div>
        <div class="mt-4">
            {{ csv }}
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref, watchEffect, onMounted } from 'vue'
import { useStore } from 'vuex'
import axios from '../axioscustom.js'
import Knopf from '../components/Knopf.vue'

const store = useStore()
const csv = ref()

const VueCsvImportData = ref(null)

const changeMap = () => {
    VueCsvImportData.VueCsvImportData.map.ks_tgz = 99
}
```

Comment: What did you try and what did not work? Please, don't describe the code but post it. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I added my code. I hope it is clearer what I´m trying to achieve